# Dúvida como separar itens retornados de um Web Service

Tags: php, html, jquery

Tenho um site em Wordpress e nele estou consumindo um Web Service, criei uma função para filtrar os campeonatos com base em algumas informações:

Sexo : M

Modalidade : 2

Categoria : 4


Se todas forem verdadeiras, ele retorna o nome do respectivo campeonato, o problema é que, se existe mais de um campeonato com as mesmas condições, ele exibe todos os nomes de uma vez, como não tenho muita experiência com esse tipo de função e é a primeira vez que consumo um Web Service, gostaria de saber se teria como exibir um campeonato por linha de tabela, para que eu possa separa-los em cada `"<a>"` usando o script jQuery que criei, desde já agradeço a ajuda!

**Teste.php**

```
<?php 
    $api_request = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/campeonatos?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SLXSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL';
    $api_response = wp_remote_get( $api_request );
    $api_data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $api_response ), true );
    $retorno = '';

if($api_data){
    foreach($api_data as $row){
        if(!is_array($row)){
            //$retorno = $retorno.'<td>'.$row.'</td>';
        }else{
            if($row['sexo'] == 'M' && $row['modalidade'] == 2 && $row['categoria'] == 4){
                $retorno .='<td>'.$row['nome'].'</td>';
            }   
        }   
    }
}
?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){

    var html = '<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="list" href="#home" role="tab"><?php echo $retorno;?></a>';

    $('#myList').html(html);
});
```

**Retorno da url**

```
 {
"codigo": "1",
"nome": "1ª Fase",
"modalidade": "9",
"categoria": "10",
"sexo": "F",
"data": "2018-04-12 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": "2018-07-23 04:07:15",
"status": "N"
},
  {
"codigo": "2",
"nome": "1ª Fase",
"modalidade": "2",
"categoria": "4",
"sexo": "M",
"data": "2018-04-05 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": "2018-07-20 01:07:40",
"status": "S"
},
  {
"codigo": "14",
"nome": "50 metros Livre Nível A",
"modalidade": "304",
"categoria": "10",
"sexo": "F",
"data": "2018-05-20 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": null,
"status": "N"
},
  {
"codigo": "15",
"nome": "CIRCUITO ESCOLAR - SÉRIE OURO",
"modalidade": "2",
"categoria": "4",
"sexo": "M",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": null,
"status": "N"
},
```

Comment: Miguel, já que é uma api você deve consultar a documentação da api para ver como pode retornar os dados de forma diferente, não há o que possamos ajudar com isso. Se você quiser manipular o resultado, coloque na resposta um exemplo do json de retorno e o que gostaria de mudar que podemos lhe ajudar

Comment: Entendi, me desculpe, é minha primeira vez com esse tipo de trabalho, vou postar o retorno do Json, porque não me deram documentação nenhuma, estou muito perdido! se você puder me ajudar, ficarei muito agradecido!

Comment: Tranquilo Miguel. Bom o json é simples, agora você precisa explicar melhor isso: *" gostaria de saber se teria como exibir um campeonato por linha de tabela"*. Não sei quais parâmetros você usou, mas não pareceu filtrar por aqueles critérios que você mencionou na pergunta, veja que tem modalidades e categorias diferentes no resultado

Comment: nessa linha, eu faço ele comparar três valores, _if($row['sexo'] == 'M' && $row['modalidade'] == 2 && $row['categoria'] == 4) {$retorno .='<td>'.$row['nome'].'</td>';_ e me retornar o nome do campeonato, mas existem mais de um campeonato que atende esses critérios, então ele retorna o nome de dois deles na mesma linha, eu gostaria que cada campeonato tivesse sua própria linha gerada dentro dessa tag html _<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="list" href="#home" role="tab"><?php echo $retorno;?></a>_

Comment: o resultado é geral, ele filtraria diferentemente de acordo com a página, mas ai eu mudaria os valores como preciso.

Comment: eu só preciso que ele divida os nomes filtrados e exiba cada um em seu <a class="list-group-item">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está usando o php direto no javascript, fica mais fácil de resolver. Primeiro você transforma a variável `$retorno` em array. Depois, você insere os valores encontrados dentro desta variável. Como mostra o código abaixo:

```
 $retortno = array(); // <- mudar para array

if($api_data){
    foreach($api_data as $row){
        if(!is_array($row)){
            //$retorno = $retorno.'<td>'.$row.'</td>';
        }else{
            if($row['sexo'] == 'M' && $row['modalidade'] == 2 && $row['categoria'] == 4){
                $retorno[] = array('valor' => '<td>'.$row['nome'].'</td>', 'id' => $row['codigo']); // <--- adiciona
            }   
        }   
    }

}
```

No javascript, com o php, você irá usar um loop para gerar o html corretamente linkando os valores, um por vez. Assim:

```
$(function(){

    var html = '';

    <?php foreach($retorno as $valor){ ?>

        html += '<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="list" href="<?php echo $valor['id'];?>" role="tab"><?php echo $valor['valor'];?></a>';

    <?php } ?>

    $('#myList').html(html);
});
```

Comment: cara, você é demais, deu certo! uma ultima dúvida, se eu quisesse chamar o id do campeonato no HREF do <a>, seria mais ou menos assim? href="+$retorno[i].['codigo']+"

Comment: porque nesse caso, eu uso o bootstrap, com a função data-toggle, pra trocar conteúdo sem redirecionar a página, então precisaria replicar o id co campeonato tanto no href do <a>, quanto no  id do <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">...</div>

Comment: @MiguelCampos vou editar a resposta pra você

Comment: Muito obrigado @Andrei Coelho, está sendo de grande ajuda!!

Comment: @MiguelCampos tranquilo. Da uma olhada.

Comment: O `$valor['id']` você poderá usar o código do evento aonde quiser.

Comment: entendi, ele me retornou o seguinte erro Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token, será que precisamos concatenar?

Comment: @MiguelCampos Desculpa, tinha feito uma edição errada. agora está certo.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente agora! não sei nem como agradecer cara, obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Tranquilo @MiguelCampos . Obrigado pela aceitação. Boa sorte!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80938/discussion-between-miguel-campos-and-andrei-coelho).